# FCPX 10.3 Audio multicam angles names to appear in main timeline?

Tags: audio, final-cut-pro-x, multi-camera

Is there a way to have the names I give audio multicam angles, appear in the main timeline?

When I expand audio components it just has the name of the whole multicam clip.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and make sure Angles is checked:

[image: Angle]

This solution worked for me and I found it here towards the bottom of the post:
https://larryjordan.com/articles/apple-final-cut-pro-x-multicam-naming-weirdness/

Comment: Yes - I also ended up applying Roles to the different voices. Then checked Clip Roles too.